# Can't view PDFs on internet archive

Tags: archive.org

I can't view pdfs archived at archive.org.  It doesn't seem to matter which site or the age.  Here are 2 examples:

[One](https://web.archive.org/web/20090114061957/http://afrh.gov/afrh/news/press/weapons_0107.pdf) and 
[Two](https://web.archive.org/web/20040723020818/http://www.wyra.org:80/2004AdvancedROWFORIT.pdf)

Is anyone else able to view the PDFs archived there?  And if so, what do I need to do so I can view them?

Comment: I have no idea, so this is a comment rather than an answer, but it's possible that archiving all of files that were affiliated with any given page could use an inordinate amount of storage.

Comment: I can view them just fine. What browser are you using? Have you tried using "Save as...", saving them locally then opening them in a desktop PDF reader?

Comment: Using Firefox.  It looks like it's the browser.  I tried the basic browser that came with my Linux installation and it worked in the browser for that and "Save as..." worked for FF.